# Printing more than one book at a time

Tags: printing

Can small number of pages per book allow for printing multiple books on a press run, or does each book have to stand on its own as an independent job?

Comment: is this a tex question? (if so could you reword the question to make that clear) or is it off topic for this site?

Comment: This is rather a question on printing technology than on TeX

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436).

Comment: Certain tasks, like the table of contents and references generally require the whole thing done as a unit.  But with plain TeX it was SOP to print one chapter at a time and the table of contents was done manually.  Basically you need to set all the counters manually at the beginning of each part to be printed.

Comment: @JohnKormylo Isn't the question about printing two or more books in one go, as opposed to printing one book in two or more goes?